# Escape in QDialog works only in modal mode?

Tags: qt, key-bindings, qdialog, non-modal

<kbd>Esc</kbd> does not work for my dialog in non-modal mode, event going to underlying window. Only adding

```
setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
```

to the dialog on creation makes the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key work and calls the `reject()` slot. Is it normal or possible to <kbd>Esc</kbd> in/from non-modal dialog?

Comment: Is your dialog in the focus (active window) when you press Esc. key?

Comment: @vahancho, yes - active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
dialog->show();
```

call to

```
// Shows the dialog as a modal dialog, blocking until the user closes it.
dialog->exec();
```

Works fine for now. Seems the only way to catch event in the dialog, non-modal does not allow this or use key event filter as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with an eventfilter, if you make your custom QDialog? If you call

```
qApp->installEventFilter(yourQDialog);
```

when creating it, you can define the function

```
bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event);
```

to catch the "esc" you are looking for. More on event filters here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter.

Comment: "maybe" not a good answer here. Try Your answer first. Why I should make such strange workaround with event filter here? Doc says nothing about.